# Updating singleton dictionary in C# DLL: An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: c#, multithreading, dll, singleton, task-parallel-library

I have a C# DLL that instantiates a singleton object for the purpose of having a global configuration for that DLL.  I followed the sixth example by Jon Skeet at http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx, and below is my singleton config class.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MyProject.Configuration
{
    public sealed class Config
    {
        private static readonly Lazy<Config> lazy = new Lazy<Config>(() => new Config());

        public static Config Instance { get { return lazy.Value; } }

        public Dictionary<string, object> Parameters { get; set; }

        private Config()
        {
            Parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        }
    }
}
```

When I access this DLL via an external system, the configuration object is properly set and everything runs fine.  However, when I attempt to call the same DLL within a Parallel.For(), an exception is thrown indicating "An item with the same key has already been added."  I checked the stack trace generated from this exception and it's definitely occurring in the dictionary used within the singleton configuration object.  See the Parallel.For() snippet below.

```
// Initialize results
var computationResults = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, Results>();

// Launch computations
Parallel.For(0, ParameterSets.Count(), i =>
{
    // Initialize and run computation
    var computationEngine = new Computation(i, ParameterSets[i]);
    computationEngine.Run();

    // Gather results
    computationResults.TryAdd(i, computationEngine.Results);
}
);
```

It seems the singleton object is being shared between the different launched threads, but I would have thought these instantiations would be separate for each DLL call. Obviously I'm wrong and I have no idea what's going on here...

Is there a way for the singleton object to be unique per thread? If not, is there some way to have these configurations unique to each thread while still providing the DLL with global access?

Comment: You didn't post the code which writes to the `Parameters` dictionary, and I bet the problem is that you call it from multiple threads. `Dictionary` is *not* thread-safe. You can safely read it from multiple threads when you're done writing to it, but don't write to it concurrently, and don't read from it while it's being written to.

Comment: I understand that.  The issue I'm having is that the when I make calls to the DLL from multiple threads, I expect the singleton object to be unique per thread call, which should result in a unique dictionary per thread.  Obviously I'm making a wrong assumption somewhere, but if you could answer my questions it would help a lot.

Comment: If you want one object per thread, try `ThreadLocal<T>` -  `Lazy<T>` will get you a real singleton.

Comment: Thanks Lucas, I will try that.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski I think you should post that as an answer.

Comment: @svick you're right, I should. I originally didn't as I couldn't figure out which one of these the OP needed ;) I'll write a proper answer with both tomorrow.